# Problem with getItems() in CC: Tweaked with Advanced Peripherals

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I'm using the Inventory Manager from Advanced Peripherals, and I'm trying to make a script that transfers my inventory to a chest but keeps the positioning of all the items. The `getItems()` function is supposed to return a table in which the keys are the slot numbers containing items and the values are the data for the items in those slots. However, that's not what I seem to be getting. The table returned by `getItems()` doesn't seem to record the slot numbers anywhere - the keys are just numbers increasing from 1 to the amount of filled slots in my inventory, no matter where the items are located.

```
local inv = peripheral.find("inventoryManager")
local invTable = inv.getItems()
for slot,item in pairs(invTable):
    print(slot..": "..item.name.." x"..item.count)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: It turns out that in the latest version of Advanced Peripherals, the slot number is stored in `item.slot` rather than as the key for the entry. This change seems to be entirely undocumented, so hopefully this post will be helpful for others encountering the same issue.